# Is there a way to do this with list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input, list-comprehension

This is my code. I would like to present this in the form of list comprehension. Is there any way?
Input is:

```
2
Krishna 67 68 69
Arjun 70 98 63
```

and the output is

```
{'Krishna':[67,68,69],'Arjuna:[70,98,63]}
```

Thank you!

```
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()
print("{:.2f}".format((sum(student_marks[query_name])/len(scores))))
```

Comment: Yes, there's, but you will need loop anyway for input data.

Comment: Even if possible the outcome wouldn't be very comprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
print(dict((name, list(map(float, line))) for name, *line in (input().split() for _ in range(int(input())))))
```

Output:

```
{'Arjun': [70.0, 98.0, 63.0], 'Krishna': [67.0, 68.0, 69.0]}
```

But pity the person who has to maintain the code.

*Your existing code is fine. Stick with what you have already.*

Comment: It might be better to replace `map()` with list comprehension to not mix coding styles.

Comment: @OlvinRoght True, but as you can rather tell from the tone of my reply, I think it's far better to stick with the OP's original code in any case. It's clear and readable. But the disease of trying to replace everything with a one-liner is quite infectious.

Comment: Maybe use the {} comprehension too instead of converting to a dict: `{name: [int(num) for num in nums] for name, *nums in (input().split() for _ in range(int(input())))}`. Either way, I agree this is bad practice.

Comment: @cabralpinto Yes, that's a good point as well. Still, we are agreed on the basic point.